# Does a "Let's Encrypt" SSL certificate work correct for port 2998 (wss/socket.io) connections?

Tags: ssl, socket.io

My site has a Let's Encrypt cert that is installed using certbot and is perfect for HTTPS connections (port 443). Works great.

I also have a node server running and I use socket.io for websocket connections, which requires its own certificate. So I give it the Let's Encrypt certificate, and that seems to work for me, though I am not 100% confident it works for all my site's users.

What has me concerned is this: when I check my cert at https://whatsmychaincert.com/ and specifically add port 2998 with my domain, I'm told my certificate chain is "misconfigured." (When I use that web site to just check my domain with no port, or specifically adding the normal SSL port `:443` to the domain name, it says the chain is perfect.)

I googled quite a bit but can't find a clear answer: does Let's Encrypt support the secure web socket protocol (`wss://`) that runs on port 2998? (And if not, how can I find an SSL cert that will work?)

Comment: You didn't configure your certificate correctly then? Have you configured the authority chain certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was giving my https server (inside node.js) the `cert.pem` file, instead of the `fullchain.pem` file. Changing to use the full chain fixed the misconfiguration issue.

Answer (score 3):

Asking if Let's Encrypt supports WebSockets or not is simply invalid. They're just an issuer. You receive a perfectly valid X.509 certificate, you can use it anywhere you want where such certificate is applicable. You can get one elsewhere too. The port under which a service is running doesn't matter as well.

Without knowing your SSL configuration we can't help you to debug this.